# Set $S={x^{3}+2x<4}$ bounded from above or below?

Tags: real-analysis

It's obvious that it won't be bound below and the LUB will be ~$1.18$, but how do you prove that it is indeed bounded from above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume that it is not bounded from above, then, by definition this means that $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ there is $x_n\in S:x_n>n$. Then you have a sequence  $\left\{x_n\right\}\subset S$ such that $x_n\to\infty$. But for this sequence $x_n^3+2x_n\to\infty$ which is a contradiction with that $x_n^3+2x_n<4$. Therefore $S$ is bounded !

Comment: I don't see what the assumption has to do with anything.

Comment: @pjs36 If it is not bounded from above , by definition this means that $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ there is $x_n\in S:x_n>n$. Then you have a sequence  $\left\{x_n\right\}\subset S$ such that $x_n\to\infty$. But for this sequence $x_n^3+2x_n\to\infty$ which is a contradiction with that $x_n^3+2x_n<4$

Comment: I'm merely pointing out that it is superfluous to assume such a thing. Your contradiction comes from your claim that "$x_n^3 + 2x_n < 4$," which, if justified, would be enough for a direct proof.

Comment: @pjs36 I can not understand what you have in mind. The set $S$ consists of such real numbers $x$ that $x^3+2x<4$. What is your concern here ?

Comment: Yes, I was clearly confused there, you're exactly right. My apologies!

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, \ x\mapsto x^3+2x$,  the derivative is $3x^2+2$ which is positive everywhere, hence your function is strictly monotone and $f(2)=12>4$ which means 2 is an upper bound for your set $S$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \ge 2$, then $x^3 + 2x \ge 2^3+2 \cdot 2 =12$.

Thus, if $x^3 + 2x < 4 < 12$, then $x < 2$. So, $2$ is an upper bound for $S$.

If $x<0$, then $x^3+2x < 0 < 4$. So $S$ contains all negative numbers and is not bounded below.

Comment: Is it possible to say it isn't bounded below?

Comment: Just so I don't have to open another question that is very related to this one. If $A=r^{2}<9$, $inf(A)=-3$ $sup(A)=3$, would something like this need to be proved?

Comment: @Achro, yes. Try it. If you get stuck, ask a separate question.